# error when trying to load image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

Hello stackoverflow community

I'm new to KineticJS and have some issues with loading and image into a canvas Element.
If I run my little snippet i get this error:

TypeError: Value could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement.

But how can i convert it into the needed Type?

Whole code for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script src="kinetic-v4.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  var dia_bg = new Image();
  var dia_bg.src = 'http://www.m133.wallerdeknaller.ch/script/dia_img/bg_diagramm.jpg';

  dia_bg.onload = function() {
   var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
   });

   var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

   var test = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 220,
    y: 50,
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    fillPatternImage: dia_bg.src,
   });

   layer.add(test);
   stage.add(layer);
  }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thx for any help right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to use `var` to set a property of an object. Get rid of the `var` where you set `dia_bg.src`.
2. Change `fillPatternImage: dia_bg.src` to `fillPatternImage: dia_bg`

Here it is working in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kcSWA/

Comment: Such an easy solution... Thx a lot!